# How do I stop a process with Ctrl-C in Term?

Tags: term, doom

I'm very new to Emacs. I've opened a terminal with `M-x term`, and started a server running on localhost. It says `Press CTRL+c to quit`. However, Ctrl-C appears to be mapped to Emacs commands.

How can I use regular terminal shortcuts within Emacs?

Note that I am using DOOM Emacs (evil-mode).

Comment: [Similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119737/how-to-kill-a-process-in-a-terminal-inside-emacs): C-c C-c for standard emacs. Don't know about evil but you can try.

Comment: thanks, perfect. pretty much same case and that solution worked. If you want to make an answer I'll accept.